# If $\frak{g}$ is a semi-simple lie algebra then every homomorphic image of $\frak{g}$ is semisimple.

Tags: lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

Could someone give me a suggestion to solve this problem?

PROBLEM:

If $\frak{g}$ is a semi-simple lie algebra then every homomorphic image of 
$\frak{g}$ is semisimple.

I was trying to prove that if $\varphi: \frak{g} \rightarrow \frak{h}$ is a homomorphism of lie algebras then the radical of
$\varphi(\frak{g})$ is zero, but I could not.

Comment: A semisimple Lie algebra is a direct sum of simple Lie algebras.

Answer (score 5):

The proof depends on the definitions and results we can use. I will assume that a Lie algebra is semisimple if it does not contain a nonzero solvable ideal.

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be semisimple, and $\varphi: \frak{g} \rightarrow \frak{h}$ be a Lie algebra homomorphism. Suppose that $\phi(\mathfrak{g})$ had a solvable ideal $I$. Then its pre-image $\phi^{-1}(I)$ would also be a solvable ideal. But since $\mathfrak{g}$ is semisimple, this pre-image would be zero. Hence its image would also be zero, i.e., $I=0$. Hence $\phi(\mathfrak{g})$ is semisimple.

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but why is the homomorphic pre-image of a solvable ideal solvable?  I've tried proving it to no avail... Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: See the proof attempt (with $f$ instead of $\phi$) [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3214824/lie-algebra-homomorphisms-preserve-semi-simplicity).

Answer (score 4):

We know that $\phi(\mathfrak g)=\mathfrak g / ker \phi$.

Since $ker\phi$ is an ideal of $\mathfrak g$, we can write $\mathfrak g=ker\phi \oplus (ker\phi)^\perp$. Here $ker\phi $ and $(ker\phi)^\perp$ are both ideals of $\mathfrak g$. (This is proved on page 23 of 'Introduction to Lie Algebras and Representation Theory-Humphreys'.) So, $\phi(\mathfrak g)=\mathfrak g / ker \phi=(ker\phi)^\perp$. Since every ideal of semisimple is semisimple, $\phi(\mathfrak g)=(ker\phi)^\perp$ is semisimple.