# Doubt on trivial representation of the lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(2)$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, representation-of-algebras

*First of all, my question is written in $II)$ section.*

### I) Groups and Representations

In group theory a *representation* is a map that is defined as:

$$\rho: G \to GL(V) \tag{1}.$$

You take a element from $G$ and creates a object in $GL(V)$ that acts on a vector space $V$.

Using the pushfoward $\cdot_{*}$ it is possible to create representations for the lie algebras as well:

$$\rho_{*}: \mathfrak{g} \to \mathrm{End}(V) \tag{2}.$$

> Furthermore, with the exponential map, $\mathrm{exp}$, you can "translate" the technology of standard Lie group theory (since in $(1)$ we are dealing with groups), into lie algebra representations as:
>
> $\require{AMScd}$
> \begin{CD}
> \mathfrak{g}@>{\rho_{*}}>>  \hspace{0.4cm}\mathrm{End}(V)\\
> @V{\mathrm{exp}}VV @VV{\mathrm{exp}}V\\
> G @>{\rho}>> GL(V)
> \end{CD}

Now, a representation is said to be *trivial* if:

$\require{AMScd} \tag{3}$
\begin{CD}
\rho:G\to GL(V)
\\ \hspace{1.5cm}a \mapsto \rho(a) := \mathrm{Id}_{GL(V)},
\end{CD}

and

$\require{AMScd} \tag{4}$
\begin{CD}
\rho_{*}:\mathfrak{g}\to \mathrm{End}(V)
\\ \hspace{2cm}a_{\mathfrak{g}} \mapsto \rho_{*}(a_{\mathfrak{g}}) := 0_{\mathrm{End}(V)}.
\end{CD}

### II) My Question

My question is: considering the explicit example of the lie algebra of $G=SU(2)$, the $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{su}(2)$. Why when do we choose the representation of the lie algebra as: $\rho_{*}:\mathfrak{su}(2)\to \mathrm{End}(\mathbb{C})$ we get:

$$\rho_{*}(a_{\mathfrak{su}(2)}) = 0_{\mathrm{End}(\mathbb{C})} \tag{5}$$

and when do we choose the representation of the lie algebra as: $\rho_{*}:\mathfrak{su}(2)\to \mathrm{End}(\mathbb{C}^2)$ we get:

$$\rho_{*}(a_{\mathfrak{su}(2)}) \neq 0_{\mathrm{End}(\mathbb{C}^2)} ?\tag{6}$$

> Another two ways to ask the same question:
>
> $1)$ Why do we **get** the trivial representation of $SU(2)$, and its lie algebra, when we choose $V=\mathbb{C}$?
>
> $2)$ Why do we **not get** the trivial representation of $SU(2)$, and its lie algebra, when we choose $V=\mathbb{C}^2$?

Comment: Not just any map, they have to be *homomorphisms* (of the respective structures, group or Lie algebra)! Correspondingly, one cannot just "choose $V=\mathbb C$ or $=\mathbb C^2$", respectively, and make any statement from that alone. You need to define a map $\rho$ in each case, and those are very different from one another. Or rather, in the first case, indeed the trivial map is the only reasonable homomorphism, whereas on $\mathbb C^2$, one can also consider a trivial representation, but there is a very interesting and highly non-trivial one as well.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg is there something special happening when your $\mathrm{End}(V)$ or $GL(V)$ are acting on $1$-dimensional vector spaces (i.e. when $\mathrm{dim}V =1$)?

Comment: @M.N.Raia the only Lie algebra structure on $\mathrm{End}(\mathbb{C})\cong \mathbb{C}$ (or indeed on any 1-dimensional space) is the trivial one. This forces a Lie algebra homomorphism $\mathfrak{su}\to \mathrm{End}(\mathbb{C})$ to be identically zero.

Comment: Note this depends also on the fact that $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ is semisimple. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3496271/semi-simple-lie-algebra-representation-of-dimension-1). Thus, as in your other question, $\mathfrak{u}(1)$ is not constrained to have only a trivial 1-dimensional representation since it is not semisimple.